# Best way to make a custom Link component for Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I make a custom Link component in Next.js? Basically what I need is a custom Link component because I have to add a conditional `onClick`. Doing this for each and every `<Link><a onClick={handleClick}</a></Link>` will become very tedious as the Link component will be used accross multiple pages.

What I have now is not going to work really good because sometimes inside the Link component there's already an `<a>` tag rendered by `react-bootstrap`

```
// components/Link.js

import Link from "next/link";
import { useContext } from "react";
import AppContext from "../../context/AppContext";

const NextLink = ({
  href,
  children,
  replace,
  scroll,
  shallow,
  locale,
  className,
}) => {
  const { someThing } = useContext(AppContext);

  const handleClick = () => {
    alert("clicked");
  };

  return (
    <Link
      href={href}
      replace={replace}
      scroll={scroll}
      shallow={shallow}
      locale={locale}
      passHref
    >
      <a onClick={someThing ? handleClick : null} className={className}>
        {children}
      </a>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NextLink;
```

Basically I am getting `someThing` from the context and if it is set to true or false. When true, it will run the `handleClick`

That is all I need, but as you can imagine adding that to each and every page component or normal component when using `import Link from "next/link";` will become very tedious.

Some of the dependencies:

```
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"next": "12.1.0",
"next-themes": "^0.2.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"sass": "^1.49.9"
```

Example of where and why it would go wrong with the new `NextLink` component:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
// import NextLink from "./Link";

import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faGlobe } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const LanguagePicker = () => {
  const { locale, asPath } = useRouter();
  return (
    <Dropdown align={{ lg: "end" }}>
      <Dropdown.Toggle
        variant="outline-secondary"
        id="language-dropdown"
        className="px-4 py-2"
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGlobe} className="me-2" />
        {locale === "en" ? "EN" : "ES"}
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Link href={asPath} locale="es" passHref>
          <Dropdown.Item className={locale === "es" ? "active" : ""}>
            Español
          </Dropdown.Item>
        </Link>
        <Link href={asPath} locale="en" passHref>
          <Dropdown.Item className={locale === "en" ? "active" : ""}>
            English
          </Dropdown.Item>
        </Link>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

export default LanguagePicker;
```

If I'd replace `<Link>` for `<NextLink>` now it will render 2 `<a>` tags because of `<Dropdown.Item>`.

Comment: I think `Dropdown.Item` can take `as` prop. Try if this works: `<Dropdown.Item as={Link}...` and remove the parent `Link` components.

Comment: That will result in:

`Error: Failed prop type: The prop href expects a string or object in <Link>, but got undefined instead. Open your browser's console to view the Component stack trace.`

Comment: Did you pass the `href` as well? `<Dropdown.Item as={Link} href={asPath}>`

Comment: I tried and works but It renders 2 `<a>` tags. which is one of the concerns as well.

Comment: Check my answer below, I believe it could work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom component link this:

```
import NextLink from "next/link";

export default function Link({ onClick, children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <NextLink {...rest} passHref>
      <a
        onClick={
          onClick
            ? (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                onClick();
              }
            : undefined
        }
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    </NextLink>
  );
}
```

Use it like this, without `onClick`:

```
import {Link} from "components/link";

<Link href={"/about"}>About</Link>
```

with `onClick`:

```
<Link href={"/about"} onClick={() => alert("test")}>About</Link>
```

in the `Dropdown`, use `DropDown.ItemText` which will prevent double `<a>` elements:

```
<Link href={"/"} onClick={() => alert("test")}>
  <Dropdown.ItemText>English</Dropdown.ItemText>
</Link>
```

If you would like to automatically add `onClick`, here is how you can modify your component:

```
import NextLink from "next/link";

export default function Link({ onClick, children, ...rest }) {
  let clickHandler = onClick;
  if (!clickHandler) {
    const shouldAddOnClick = /* Code that decides if onClick needs to be added */;

    if (shouldAddOnClick) {
      clickHandler = () => {/* ... */};
    }
  }

  return (
    <NextLink {...rest} passHref>
      <a
        onClick={
          clickHandler
            ? (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                clickHandler();
              }
            : undefined
        }
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    </NextLink>
  );
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I think it would not work. From what I understand is that an `onClick` would not work directly on the Next.js `<Link>` component. Therefore you'd always have to apply it to the `<a>` tag. I might get it wrong and your solution would automatically add `onClick` on the `<a>` in the `Dropdown` example. I'll try it it out asap. The `onClick` is conditionally though, so I want to automate it and not have to add the `onClick` each time the application needs it. It is because I am running an external script that needs an event when activated.

Comment: The `onClick` isn't being passed to the Next.js component, but rather to the component that I created in the first code sample. Although, looking into it I see some issues with using `onClick` on the `Dropdown.Item` element. You will have to use `Dropdown.ItemText` instead, so that it doesn't print two `<a>` elements. I have edited my answer to include a better solution.

Comment: As for the automation, if you add a custom components like in the first code block, you can easily do it there, then you won't have to pass `onClick` every time you use it.